# Find $A^{20}x$ using eigenvectors and eigenvalues.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Find $A^{20}x$

A is a 3X3 matrix with the following eigenvectors and eigenvalues:

$V_1 = [1, 0, 0]... V_2 = [1, 1, 0]... V_3 = [1, 1, 1]$ corresponding to Eigenvalues..

$\lambda1 = -1/3, \lambda2 = 1/3, \lambda3 = 1$

$X = [2, 1, 2]$

My solution does not match the provided solution in the text book, and I'm unsure of why. I followed the same process as an example that was done in the text book to get my answer.

First we write X as a linear combination of $V_1, V_2, V_3$:

$X = 1V_1 - 1V_2 + 2V_3$

$A^{20}x = A^{20}(1V_1 - V_2 + 2V_3)$

Distribute our $A^{20}x$

$= 1(A^{20}V_1) - (A^{20}V_2) + 2(A^{20}V_3)$

Sub in our lambda values

$= 1(-1/3)^{20}[1, 0, 0] - (1/3)^{20}[1, 1, 0] + 2(1)^{20}[1, 1, 1]$

My Result:

\begin{bmatrix}
    (-1/3)^{20}       & (-1/3)^{20} & 2\\
    0       & (-1/3)^{20} & 2  \\
    0       & 0 & 2
\end{bmatrix}

The Textbook's Solution:

\begin{bmatrix}
          & 2 & \\
           & (2*3^{20} -1)/3^{20} &  \\
          & 0 & 
\end{bmatrix}

Comment: You were addding $3$ matrices whose dimensions were $3 \times 1$. How do you get a square matrix by adding rectangular matrices? Add up component wise, do not concatenate the matrices as columns!

Answer (score 1):

You have
$$A^{20}x=\left(-\frac{1}{3}\right)^{20}V_1-\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)^{20}V_2+2V_3,$$
and this is
$$\left(-\frac{1}{3}\right)^{20}\left(\begin{array}{c}1\\0\\0\end{array}\right)-\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)^{20}\left(\begin{array}{c}1\\1\\0\end{array}\right)+2\left(\begin{array}{c}1\\1\\1\end{array}\right)=
\left(\begin{array}{c}2\\-\left(\frac{1}{30}\right)^{20}+2\\2\end{array}\right).$$